# Html.ActionLink where id is URL path causes 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have limited knowledge so beat me up as needed.

I have created a controller using the EF with ASPX(C#) views.  I inherited this setup.

The PK in the target table/EF is an actual URL.  So when you click the link ActionLink feeds the URL and I receive a 404.

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ImagePath })
```

So id= /foldername/foldername2/image.jpg

This causes the browser to try and load the resource.

Can someone give me a clue how to process this "id" accordingly?

Comment: Can you post your Edit action?

Comment: public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            QuoteViewPublicDetail quoteviewpublicdetail = db.QuoteViewPublicDetails.Single(q => q.ImagePath == id);
            ViewBag.QuoteViewPublicId = new SelectList(db.QuoteViewPublics, "Id", "ApprovedIP", quoteviewpublicdetail.QuoteViewPublicId);
            return View(quoteviewpublicdetail);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed your routing to accept this sort of id?

If not then you will need to go into your global.asax.cs file and edit the map routes.

This should help you with that:

[Creating custom routes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                "ImgNotes",                                           // Route name
                "ImgNotes/Edit/{id}",                            // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "ImgNotes", action = "Edit" }  // Parameter defaults

Answer (score 0):

The EDIT action in the controller... is waiting for a string ID or Integer one?

If the EDIT action accepts strings, then you could just scape the ID's "/"... that way the routing engine will no think the ID is a URL.